# Is it okay to ask questions concerning suggestions for one-day excursions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, I'd like to to do some one day excursion from the city where I'm living. But I'm running out of interesting things to do. So I think Travel SE would be an interesting place to get more suggestions. But I'm not sure if it is okay to ask for suggestions for a one-day trip.

Is this really travel related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly wouldn't be the first - like the [one on Cairo day activities](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/what-are-the-best-day-trips-for-a-single-traveler-staying-in-cairo), or the [one on day trips in Southern California](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/southern-california-nature-day-trips), for example.  As long as it's worded right, such a question could also be invaluable for a traveller coming to your city in the future!

Comment: Yes day trips are certainly covered by paper travel guidebooks and we have a few such questions so I think it was me who created a [tag:day-trips] tag for them.